# Getting "TypeError: this.state.users.map is not a function" for deployed React application only

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, axios

Built a web application using React to pull user information from a Firestore database. When running the application locally, it runs flawless and I can load the users information. After deploying it, I now receive a "TypeError: this.state.users.map is not a function" message and the page won't even load. Why would it work in work before deploying it and what would be the fix?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import AllCoaches from '../components/search/AllCoaches';
import Banner from '../components/layout/banner';
import axios from 'axios';

// MUI Stuff
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import CircularProgress from '@material-ui/core/CircularProgress';


class coaches extends Component {
    state = {
        users: []
      }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('/coaches')
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res.data)
            this.setState({
                users: res.data
            })
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }

    render() {
    let coaches = this.state.users ? (
        this.state.users.map((user) => <AllCoaches user={user}/>)
    ) : ( <CircularProgress/> );
      return (
        <Grid container>
        <Banner/>
            {coaches}
        </Grid>
        );  
    }   
}


export default coaches
```

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(res.data)`?

Comment: When I run it locally the output is: 
Array(5) 0: {userId: "name0", bio: info0,} 1: {userId: "name1", bio: info1,} 2: {userId: "name2", bio: info2,} 3: {userId: "name3", bio: info3,} 4: {userId: "name4", bio: info4,} 5: {userId: "name5", bio: info5,}length: 5
__proto__: Array(0)

Comment: In your deployed version, are there any errors being catched in this line: `.catch(err => console.log(err));`? Also, in the deployed version, what is the output of `console.log(res.data)` ?

Comment: In the deployed version, the only error being caught is the "TypeError: this.state.users.map is not a function".

Also in the deployed version, the output for the console.log(res.data) is what looks like index.html file: 
`<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"/><link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico"/>.....</body></html>`

Comment: I would say that something is wrong in your routes for axios.get() in the deployed version then, as this is a weird and unexpected result. It's likely redirecting you to wrong place, can you check that?